# using avg, group by, and case together - db2

Tags: group-by, db2, case, average

i have the following working code to return every combination of location, state, and monthyear.

```
select *
from openquery (jw,'
select distinct a.location, a.state, a.monthyear
from (
    select clm.location, clm.state,
    case 
        when EFDT>=''2017-09-01'' and EFDT<=''2017-09-30'' Then ''Sept 2017''
        when EFDT>=''2017-10-01'' and EFDT<=''2017-10-31'' Then ''Oct 2017''
        when EFDT>=''2017-11-01'' and EFDT<=''2017-11-30'' Then ''Nov 2017''
        when EFDT>=''2017-12-01'' and EFDT<=''2017-12-31'' Then ''Dec 2017''
        when EFDT>=''2018-01-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-01-31'' Then ''Jan 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-02-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-02-28'' Then ''Feb 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-03-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-03-31'' Then ''March 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-04-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-04-30'' Then ''April 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-05-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-05-31'' Then ''May 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-06-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-06-30'' Then ''June 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-07-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-07-31'' Then ''July 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-08-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-08-31'' Then ''Aug 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-09-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-09-30'' Then ''Sept 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-10-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-10-31'' Then ''Oct 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-11-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-11-30'' Then ''Nov 2018''
        when EFDT>=''2018-12-01'' and EFDT<=''2018-12-31'' Then ''Dec 2018''
        ELSE ''null''
    END as monthyear
    from alias.table1 clm
    where ....
) a
group by location, state, monthyear
order by monthyear
with ur')
```

now i'm struggling on adding in the AVG to get the average time for each combination, the code would be:

```
avg(days(LSDT)-days(EFDT))
```

how can i use avg in combination with group by and case? any advice is appreciated. i need to show the average time between these two dates for each combination of channel, state, and monthyear

Comment: ... what's wrong with just doing the average?  The grouping should still bucket everything correctly (because it happens after the math).  Side notes: Given what's shown here, you don't need the subquery.  You don't need `DISTINCT` if you output all the columns in a `GROUP BY` (if you're lucky it's ignored).  Always query dates as upper-bound exclusive - `<` (so here, `when EFDT>=''2017-09-01'' and EFDT<''2017-10-01'' Then ''Sept 2017''`).  Also, it's possible to turn your `CASE` into a table reference, [to be used as a range table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152098/812837)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select location, state, monthyear, avg(days(LSDT)-days(EFDT)) as days
from (
select clm.location, clm.state, clm.lsdt, clm.efdt
, case 
    when EFDT between date('2017-09-01') and date('2018-12-31') then to_char(EFDT, 'Mon')||' '||year(EFDT) 
    else 'null' 
  end monthyear
from alias.table1 clm
)
group by location, state, monthyear
order by monthyear;
```

Comment: very good! i had to change around a couple things to make this db2 friendly, the ||' '|| concat didn't work so i used to_char(EFDT,''mon'')concat(year(EFDT)) but this worked! appreciate your help mark